# How can you target multiple platform's inside Android NDK Application.mk

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

I need a version of my application that supports PIE (Position Independent Executable) for Android L and one that does not for older devices.

Can this be done with a single Application.mk?

The Application.mk for older devices looks like:

> ```
> APP_PLATFORM := android-10
> APP_ABI      := armeabi x86
> APP_STL      := stlport_static
> ```

But for newer devices it's:

> ```
> APP_PLATFORM := android-L
> APP_ABI      := armeabi-v7a
> APP_STL      := stlport_static
> ```

---

### Answer

It can't be done inside a single Application.mk, but you can specify an Application.mk like:

```
~/ndk/ndk-build
~/ndk/ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application-L.mk
```

Note the docs falsely call this NDK_APP_APPLICATION_MK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible with the NDK make system. All I can suggest is have the two files and two separate build trees.